# How to design Doctrine 2 Entities

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two MySQL tables (`news` and `news_lng`). News table `content id`, `from_date`, `to_date` and `leading_image` fields. `news_lng` table contains `id`, `news_id`, `lng`, `title` and `body` fields.

```
news
id | from_date  | to_date    | leading_image
1  | 2017-05-01 | 0000-00-00 | test.jpg

news_lng
id | news_id | lng   | title | body
1  | 1       | en_GB | test  | test body
2  | 1       | en_US | test  | test content
```

How to design doctrine 2 entities ?

1.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\Admin\Repository\NewsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 */
class News {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="from_date")
     */
    protected $fromDate;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="to_date")
     */
    protected $toDate;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="leading_image")
     */
    protected $leadingImage;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\NewsLng", fetch="EAGER", mappedBy="news_id")
     */
    private $translations;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // getters and setters ...//
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_lng")
 */
class NewsLng {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="id")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Admin\Entity\News", inversedBy="translations", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="news_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $news_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lng")
     */
    protected $lng;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title")
     */
    protected $tile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="body")
     */
    protected $body;

    // getters and setters ...//
}
```

2. Or I must use doctrine 2 Class Table Inheritance ?

What are best practices in doctrine 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case using a relation is appropriate solution. Table inheritance is designed for something else.